# Win10: what is the folder "\Data\$OF" in FileHistory?

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I have turn on file history and in the folder `user/computer/data` there are two folders. One is `C` and the other one is `$OF`.

The folder `C` simply reflects the structure of the folders I choose the add to file history. 
The folder `$OF` contains many subfolders. There are named with a string of digits (ei: 568, 5226). I can recognize my files in these subfolders but they are not organized in the same way that they are on my desktop.

So what is this folder `$OF`? What is the logic used to organized the files in it?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-files/file-history-and-the-of-folder-on-my-external/ba3bf6bf-7d09-4c93-a1ba-9689f2739981) on answer.microsoft.com, `$OF` holds files whose pathnames are too long to be stored on your backup device.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that each of the directories have a particular purpose. Each one contains a type of file (ie .jpg).  So all .jpg's that have a too long a file name gets put in this directory whil other extensions each have their own directory numeric name.